# Retrieve path and file name of current QGIS project in Python

Tags: qgis, python

Is there a way to get the path and the file name of the current QGIS project from a Python script? 
I'm currently trying to develop a Python plugin for QGIS and I need to create a file with a similar name in the same folder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following method from [the QgsProject class](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html) to retrieve the path to the project file:

```
from qgis.core import *
prjpath = QgsProject.instance().fileName()
```

If there is no project loaded, or the current project has not yet been saved, this will return an empty QString:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'')
```

You can convert the project file path further to a Python Unicode string (if needed) with:

```
unicode(prjpath)
```

However, if you intend to have your plugin be cross-platform, you are better off not working with the file path as a string in Python, but leverage Qt's excellent [QFileInfo class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qfileinfo.html):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *

prjfi = QFileInfo(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
prjfi.absolutePath()  # what you are probably looking for
```

The QFileInfo class (along with [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qfile.html) and [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qdir.html)) will handle many cross-platform filesystem issues for you, and inclusively provide methods that would otherwise be spread across more Python classes.

Comment: you can also use `QgsProject.instance().homePath()` to get the path directly