# Change default saving folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, tools

Probably a basic issue, but still something that irks me and I can't find an answer online.

I want to change the default folder for saving new shapes/processing outputs from "last used folder" to "project folder" or "something in relation to project folder" - is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can alter the default saving location through Options > Processing.

[image: Overview of the options for the processing toolbox]

This also allows you to specify a pre-execution python script which I assume could be written to set the save folder (details here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hooks.html)

This answer indicates you can grab the current project path quite easily: [Retrieve path and file name of current QGIS project in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34005/retrieve-path-and-file-name-of-current-qgis-project-in-python/34018)

Comment: Thanks, probably I was just too stupid to use the correct phrase on google ^^